# Linq query to display number of users registered based on month

Tags: c#, linq

```
var list = dbcontext.StudentProfiles.GroupBy(u => u.CreatedDate.Value.Month)
                .Select(u => new UserData
                {
                    // UserCount = u.Count(),
                    Month = u.FirstOrDefault().CreatedDate.Value.Month.ToString()
                    // UserCount = dbcontext.StudentProfiles.Where(u => u.CreatedDate.Value.Month ==0).Count()
                     UserCount = dbcontext.StudentProfiles.Where(u => u.CreatedDate).Count()
                }).ToList();
```

i need to display month wise count ex: january:23, feb:86, march:45 etc...... based on their registered date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
var list = dbcontext.StudentProfiles.GroupBy(u => u.CreatedDate.Value.Month)
                .Select(group => new UserData
                {
                    Month = group.Key.ToString(),
                    UserCount = group.Count()
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
 var result =  _unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetAll().GroupBy(u => u.CreatedDateTime.Month)
                         .Select(group => new UserGraficViewModel
                         {
                             Month = DateTime.FromOADate(group.Key).ToString("MMMM"),
                             Count = group.Count()
                         }).ToList();
```